# How would one build a model of their project?

Tags: asp.net, architecture

I've been asked to model my application. I'm not clear what this means, Perhaps something related to the architecture of my project?. Does it mean giving them a break-up of the classes? Or something like building a use-case or class diagram? Or perhaps something else?

EDIT: I cannot ask them!

Comment: I knew this reply was coming! But that isn't an option for me. So I'm trying to figure this out myself, with asking them being the last resort.

Comment: A class diagram is usually considered a model. Or if they are less technical they might want a diagram that shows the physical and logical components.

Comment: Or maybe [this](http://www.wonderlandmodels.com/media/managed/large/mk6102.jpg) *who knows*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with UML (Unified Modelling Language). It allows you to lay out classes, methods, inheritance, etc. in a graphical format.

A quick Google search gives this FOSS option:

[Umbrello UML Modeller](http://uml.sourceforge.net/)

EDIT: Just realized that's linux-only, so here's the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unified_Modeling_Language_tools) for a whole bunch of other options.